# How to fill the combobox dynamically during runtime with WPF & Powershell

Tags: wpf, powershell, data-binding

I have a Datagrid element with two columns, which contains two combobox elements. The first combobox is filled statically before the runtime of the program.
I now want to fill the second combobox during runtime. The content of this combobox is different, depending on the value of the first combobox ($comboBox.SelectedItem) .

Normally I can do this quite easily with the following method:

```
 $comboBox.Add_DropDownClosed({
                [void]$comboBox2.Items.Add("some-item")
                }
 })
```

but I think i can't control the comboboxes with a variable because of the binding (at least i supose so). I would be grateful for an example with Powershell. My knowledge in C# is still too basic to implement it there.

This is my example code:

```
Add-Type –assemblyName PresentationFramework

Add-Type –assemblyName PresentationCore

Add-Type –assemblyName WindowsBase



 #XAML
$inputXML = @"
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.Window4"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Combobox in DataGrid" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="399" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="772">
            <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay,
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                    AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                            <CheckBox.LayoutTransform>
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
                            </CheckBox.LayoutTransform>
                        </CheckBox>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Combobox" Visibility="Visible" Width="100">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                               <ComboBox
                               ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Combobox}"
                               SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Combobox, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                            </ComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Hostname" Visibility="Visible" Width="100">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Label Content="{Binding Hostname}" >
                            </Label>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Combobox2" Visibility="Visible" Width="100">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                               <ComboBox
                               ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Combobox2}"
                               SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Combobox2, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                            </ComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="IP" Visibility="Visible" Width="100">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Label Content="{Binding IP}" >
                            </Label>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="MAC" Visibility="Visible" Width="100">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Label Content="{Binding MAC}" >
                            </Label>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
"@

$inputXML = $inputXML -replace 'mc:Ignorable="d"', '' -replace "x:N", 'N' -replace '^<Win.*', '<Window'
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('presentationframework')
[xml]$XAML = $inputXML
#Read XAML

$reader = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
try {
    $Form = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)
}
catch {
    Write-Warning ("Unable to parse XML, with error: $($Error[0])`n" +
                   "Ensure that there are NO SelectionChanged or " +
                   "TextChanged properties in your textboxes (PowerShell cannot process them)")
    throw
}


#===========================================================================
# Load XAML Objects In PowerShell
#===========================================================================

$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | ForEach-Object { "trying item $($_.Name)";
    try { Set-Variable -Name "WPF$($_.Name)" -Value $Form.FindName($_.Name) -ErrorAction Stop }
    catch { throw }
}

function Get-FormVariables {
    if ($global:ReadmeDisplay -ne $true) { 
        Write-Host "If you need to reference this display again, run Get-FormVariables" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        $global:ReadmeDisplay = $true 
    }
    Write-Host "Found the following interactable elements from our form" -ForegroundColor Cyan
    Get-Variable WPF*
}

Get-FormVariables


#===========================================================================
# Load Data into DataGrid
#===========================================================================

class myRow{
[Array]$Combobox
[string]$Hostname
}



$test1 = New-Object myRow -Property @{Hostname = "PC1"; Combobox = "TEST1","TEST2"}
$test2 = New-Object myRow -Property @{Hostname = "PC2"; Combobox = "TEST1","TEST2" }
$test3 = New-Object myRow -Property @{Hostname = "PC3"; Combobox = "TEST1","TEST2" }



$WPFDataGrid.ItemsSource = @($test1,$test2,$test3)
#===========================================================================
# Shows the form
#===========================================================================

$async = $Form.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync( {
        [void]$Form.ShowDialog()

})

$async.Wait() | Out-Null
```

Comment: Can you not use $comboBox.Add_SelectedIndexChanged event?

Comment: @Scepticalist Unfortunately, I couldn't do it this way...or I did it wrong. The code is now completely uploaded here on Stackowerflow, if you want to test something.